# Language problem with flash embedding

Tags: flash, embed

I have a certain problem. I've uploaded a Chatango chat-box on a site of mine, and it worked fine, until I added <'param name="wmode" value="transparent"/> to make the Chat-box transparent, because it fits nicer to my site. In that case, the browser would take as a default that my Keyboard is set to English, and so I cannot use some characters, while some others are switched, because I'm otherwise using a Slovenian keyboard setting. How do I make the chat-box transparent without the change in my Keyboard language?

Answer (score 0):

Setting wmode transparent will always cause problems. My advice is to find a design workaround.

Comment: That doesn't really help much.. Changing the design will make it look much less appealing, which is why I don't want to resort to that option.